# "password not given" or "Wi-Fi network could not be found" Kubuntu 22.10 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, password

update 2: I am looking to the wifi connections that I have avaible, they are:

IN-USE  BSSID              SSID          MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY

- ```
    78:E9:CF:DF:73:FE  DAVI-5G       Infra  44    540 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2     
    66:E9:CF:DF:73:FE  DAVI          Infra  44    540 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2
  ```

Now, It's seems both of them are in the channel 44, this can be the issue? I have no idea if it's make sense but well, I don't know where to look anymore

---

update: A new issue is happening, it's switch randomly from the previous to the new one:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: The Wi-Fi network could not be found
```

---

I am trying to connect using a wifi usb dongle, I had always a hard time before updating to 22.10 and the new kernel, but now I can't connect at all. If I connect the connection can't keep up for a long time or just is really slow.

the model of the wifi is:

```
Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
```

---

```
nmcli c up DAVI-5G
```

---

```
Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network 'DAVI-5G'.
Warning: password for '802-11-wireless-security.psk' not given in 'passwd-file' and nmcli cannot ask without '--ask' option.
Error: Connection activation failed: Secrets were required, but not provided
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=60caf727-5ae3-425e-a4d4-1cda9369f728 + NM_DEVICE=wlxa0d768202865' to get more details.
```

---

```
journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=60caf727-5ae3-425e-a4d4-1cda9369f728 + NM_DEVICE=wlxa0d768202865
```

---

```
jan 13 17:37:07 mimi NetworkManager[833]: <info>  [1673642227.0987] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:37:07 mimi NetworkManager[833]: <info>  [1673642227.1987] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
jan 13 17:37:45 mimi NetworkManager[833]: <info>  [1673642265.8135] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: need-auth -> deactivating (reason 'unmanaged', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:37:45 mimi NetworkManager[833]: <info>  [1673642265.8259] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: deactivating -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:37:46 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642266.0690] device (wlxa0d768202865): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
jan 13 17:37:46 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642266.0693] manager: (wlxa0d768202865): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
jan 13 17:37:46 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642266.0694] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
jan 13 17:37:46 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642266.2194] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
jan 13 17:37:46 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642266.2203] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:38:05 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642285.5671] device (wlxa0d768202865): Activation: starting connection 'DAVI-5G' (60caf727-5ae3-425e-a4d4-1cda9369f728)
jan 13 17:38:05 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642285.5672] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:38:05 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642285.5675] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:38:05 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642285.5678] device (wlxa0d768202865): Activation: (wifi) access point 'DAVI-5G' has security, but secrets are required.
jan 13 17:38:05 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642285.5678] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:38:05 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642285.5679] sup-iface[a98432f14e7e8efc,1,wlxa0d768202865]: wps: type pbc start...
jan 13 17:38:05 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642285.5687] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:38:05 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642285.5689] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:38:05 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642285.5691] device (wlxa0d768202865): Activation: (wifi) connection 'DAVI-5G' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
jan 13 17:38:05 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642285.5901] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> associating
jan 13 17:38:12 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642292.7360] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
jan 13 17:38:12 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642292.8410] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
jan 13 17:38:19 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642299.1433] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
jan 13 17:38:20 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642300.5919] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
jan 13 17:38:21 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642301.0924] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
jan 13 17:38:27 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642307.3327] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
jan 13 17:38:30 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <warn>  [1673642310.7038] device (wlxa0d768202865): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
jan 13 17:38:30 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642310.7039] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:38:30 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642310.7040] sup-iface[a98432f14e7e8efc,1,wlxa0d768202865]: wps: type pbc start...
jan 13 17:38:30 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <warn>  [1673642310.7042] device (wlxa0d768202865): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
jan 13 17:38:30 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <warn>  [1673642310.8808] device (wlxa0d768202865): no secrets: No agents were available for this request.
jan 13 17:38:30 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642310.8808] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:38:30 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <warn>  [1673642310.8811] device (wlxa0d768202865): Activation: failed for connection 'DAVI-5G'
jan 13 17:38:30 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642310.8812] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:38:32 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642312.7738] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
jan 13 17:41:54 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642514.0477] device (wlxa0d768202865): Activation: starting connection 'DAVI-5G' (60caf727-5ae3-425e-a4d4-1cda9369f728)
jan 13 17:41:54 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642514.0478] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:41:54 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642514.0481] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:41:54 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642514.0483] device (wlxa0d768202865): Activation: (wifi) access point 'DAVI-5G' has security, but secrets are required.
jan 13 17:41:54 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642514.0483] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:41:54 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642514.0484] sup-iface[a98432f14e7e8efc,1,wlxa0d768202865]: wps: type pbc start...
jan 13 17:41:54 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642514.0492] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:41:54 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642514.0494] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:41:54 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642514.0496] device (wlxa0d768202865): Activation: (wifi) connection 'DAVI-5G' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
jan 13 17:42:06 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642526.9737] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
jan 13 17:42:13 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642533.3872] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
jan 13 17:42:19 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <warn>  [1673642539.7035] device (wlxa0d768202865): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
jan 13 17:42:19 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642539.7035] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:42:19 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642539.7037] sup-iface[a98432f14e7e8efc,1,wlxa0d768202865]: wps: type pbc start...
jan 13 17:42:19 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <warn>  [1673642539.7038] device (wlxa0d768202865): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
jan 13 17:42:20 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642540.2482] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
jan 13 17:42:20 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642540.2540] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
jan 13 17:42:26 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <warn>  [1673642546.7213] device (wlxa0d768202865): no secrets: User canceled the secrets request.
jan 13 17:42:26 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642546.7214] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:42:26 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <warn>  [1673642546.7216] device (wlxa0d768202865): Activation: failed for connection 'DAVI-5G'
jan 13 17:42:26 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642546.7217] device (wlxa0d768202865): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jan 13 17:42:27 mimi NetworkManager[4678]: <info>  [1673642547.4566] device (wlxa0d768202865): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
```

---

```
ifconfig -a
```

---

```
enp7s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 24:4b:fe:0c:44:9e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enx0217ff1544d3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.71.68  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.71.255
        inet6 fe80::d5f9:5d93:c2f8:4f7a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:17:ff:15:44:d3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 17175  bytes 14421233 (14.4 MB)
        RX errors 3  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 3
        TX packets 13469  bytes 3002498 (3.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6258  bytes 566031 (566.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6258  bytes 566031 (566.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlxa0d768202865: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether a0:d7:68:20:28:65  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 399 (399.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

```
sudo dkms status
```

---

```
rtl8821cu/5.12.0, 5.19.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
```

---

```
nmcli device wifi connect DAVI-5G password 1234567890
```

---

```
Connection activation failed: (53) The Wi-Fi network could not be found.
```

---

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

---

```
78:E9:CF:DF:73:FE DAVI-5G Infra 44 540 Mbit/s 62 ▂▄▆_ WPA2
```

---

That's all I can think at the moment, any suggestion?

TY

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistype, it's 22.10

Comment: Please try: `nmcli device wifi connect DAVI-5G password 1234567890` Of course, susbstitute your actual password.

Comment: @chili555
Error: Connection activation failed: (53) The Wi-Fi network could not be found.

Comment: Does it appear here? `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: @chili555

 78:E9:CF:DF:73:FE  DAVI-5G   Infra  44    540 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA2

Comment: I'm puzzled. First NM can't see the network but now it can. Please try again.

Comment: The thing is, all the times I do nmcli device wifi list it's always show all the connections...
It's just can't connect.
Sometimes complains about the password (but always ask for it no matter how many times I give it)
Sometimes it's says that network could not be find.
This usb wifi was working in previous kernel, but now it's not.
I did updated to the new driver following the instructions on:
https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu-20210118
I did using ./install-driver.sh not make install
and like i said it's even on "sudo dkms status" as:
rtl8821cu/5.12.0, 5.19.0-29-generic, x86_64

Comment: Ok, it connect but... With 0 speed, I can't post the print here but it's says that the speed connection was 0. So I could do anything, when I tried to open google it's said I was with no internet connection.

This is what is happening since the update.
To be honest, I could connect with regular speed one single time and after a few hours the connection dropped.
The times I am able to connect, this is what happens, 0 speed.

Comment: tried again:

Error: Connection activation failed: (7) Secrets were required, but not provided.

Comment: 78:E9:CF:DF:73:FE  DAVI-5G       Infra  44    540 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2     
  66:E9:CF:DF:73:FE  DAVI          Infra  44    540 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2 

It's possible that the fact that DAVI-5G and DAVI are both in the same channel is the issue?

Comment: No. However, I note that the signal strength is very low for both: 59 and 52/100 respectively. Are you far from both? Are both antenna connectors firmly in place on your wireless device?

Comment: Not that far... But this antenna have low quality. I will try to get a better one (and one that works in linux out of the box).
But like I said, it was working before the kernel update

Comment: What is the driver for the wireless device? Maybe it has a parameter related to antenna selection.

Comment: rtl8821cu/5.12.0

Comment: Sorry, I have no other suggestions.

Comment: no problem, thank you